# pyspark extremely slow collect before broadcasting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

DF1 needs to filter out rows where columnA is present in DF2.
DF2 is 10% of DF1. 80mb/800mb.

```
DF2=spark.read.parquet(s3_bucket) #80mb
df_column = DF2.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["columnA"]).lower()).collect()
columnaA_list_broadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(df_column)
...then df1 does is in...
```

However, the stage for collect takes an hour.

```
[x['columnA'] for x in DF2.select('columnA').collect()]
```

also takes time.

Is there a way to spark read directly broadcasted to all executors? instead of splitting to chunks then again recombining to all?

Broadcast anti_left also takes time.

Comment: A leftanti join seems the most straightforward, tbh. how long does the leftanti join take?

Comment: it usually takes around an hour @ksgj1. is there a way to read the df directly broadcasted to all executors instead of being split up?